# How to detect tableView cell touched or clicked in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get `index` of selected item in `TableView` and start some activity after that. Unfortunately most of solutions that I found are in objective-c or do not work.

Method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` don't print the `cell` label..

Can somebody help me please?

```swift
import UIKit
import ResearchKit

class TaskListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    let tasks=[("Short walk"),
        ("Audiometry"),
        ("Finger tapping"),
        ("Reaction time"),
        ("Spatial span memory")
    ]
    
    
    //how many sections are in your table
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    //return int how many rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    //what are the contents
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        
        var (testName) = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text=testName
        return cell
    }
    
    // give each table section a name
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return "Tasks"
        
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
        
        println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }  
}
```

After a few tries I changed the code to a different one from tutorial that I found. And it doesn't work too. Now I'm thinking this is the issue with iOS simulator...

```swift
import UIKit
import ResearchKit

class TaskListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet
    var tableView: UITableView?
    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected cell #\(items[indexPath.row])!")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you want the value from cell then you don't have to recreate cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println(tasks[indexPath.row])
}
```

Task would be as follows :

```
let tasks=["Short walk",
    "Audiometry",
    "Finger tapping",
    "Reaction time",
    "Spatial span memory"
]
```

also you have to check the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to set identifier.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    var (testName) = tasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text=testName
    return cell
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 45):

**In Swift 3.0**

You can find the event for the touch/click of the cell of tableview through it delegate method. As well, can find the section and row value of the cell like this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
       print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 16):

A of couple things that need to happen...

1. The view controller needs to extend the type `UITableViewDelegate`
2. The view controller needs to include the `didSelectRowAt` function.
3. The table view must have the view controller assigned as its delegate.

---

Below is one place where assigning the delegate could take place (within the view controller).

```
override func loadView() {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    view = tableView
}
```

And a simple implementation of the `didSelectRowAt` function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Problem was solved by myself using tutorial of [weheartswift](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/)

[image]

Comment: Does the selected answer actually fix the issue? If it does not fix the issue, please write a solution onto your answer or select the appropriate answer to fix the question you asked. Just because someone offers help and a possible solution, doesn't mean their answer should be selected as the correct one. Please fix this.

Answer (score 8):

This worked good for me:

```html
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
        print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
```

The output should be:

```
section: 0
row: 0
```

Comment: Your answer appears duplicate, as this Answer appears very similar to the above Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41583381/40867

Answer (score 7):

Inherit the tableview delegate and datasource.
Implement delegates what you need.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

And Finally implement this delegate

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt  
     indexPath: IndexPath) {
     print("row selected : \(indexPath.row)")
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

**To get an elements from Array in tableView cell touched or clicked in swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text= arr_AsianCountries[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let indexpath = arr_AsianCountries[indexPath.row]
print("indexpath:\(indexpath)")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 # Check delegate? first must be connected owner of view controller

    # Simple implementation of the didSelectRowAt function.

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         print("row selection: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I screw up on the every time! Just make sure the `tableView` delegate and `dataSource` are declared in `viewDidLoad`. Then I normally populate a few arrays to simulate returned data and then take it from there!

```
//******** Populate Table with data ***********
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? SetupCellView
    cell?.ControllerLbl.text = ViewContHeading[indexPath.row]
    cell?.DetailLbl.text = ViewContDetail[indexPath.row]
    cell?.StartupImageImg.image = UIImage(named: ViewContImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell!
}
```