# How to press on a tableview cell to present a view controller with the text in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Essentially I have a view controller called **FirstViewController**, this view controller contains a table view within it called **listTableView**.

I would like to tap on one of the cells in the table view **listTableView** and present whatever text was in the cell as the navigation controller title.

The navigation controller that appears when the cell is tapped is called **showDetailsViewController**.

How can this be done?

The following is what I have written in the **FirstViewController**

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FeedModelProtocol  {
    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedStock : StockModel = StockModel()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set delegates and initialize FeedModel


        self.listTableView.delegate = self
        self.listTableView.dataSource = self

        let feedModel = FeedModel()
        feedModel.delegate = self
        feedModel.downloadItems()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBAction func reloadData(_ sender: Any) {

        print("reload pressed")
        listTableView.reloadData()
        viewDidLoad()
        _ = AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519)
    }



    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items

        print("item feed loaded")
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        myCell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        // Get the stock to be shown
        let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
        // Configure our cell title made up of name and price


        let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")


        print(titleStr)
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

        return myCell
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

What is the issue with this code:

**NOTE:**
The restoration id of the tableview is **scheduleTable**

```
var homeworkIdentifierFromTableViewCell = ""
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        homeworkIdentifierFromTableViewCell = feedItems[indexPath.row].myCell
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "scheduleTable", sender: self)
        listTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
    let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")
    print(titleStr)


}
```

Comment: set identifier for viewController on main Storyboard same like name on navigation title. And then instantiate controller with by passing title in identifier parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the didSelectRowAt to notice what cell was clicked and store what the text in the cell was (homeworkArray is the list of cells from a struct. Homeworkidentifier is a value in the struct).

```
var homeworkIdentifierFromTableViewCell = ""
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        homeworkIdentifierFromTableViewCell = homeworkArray[indexPath.row].homeworkIdentifier

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeworktoExpandHomework", sender: self)
        homeworkTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }
```

Then, you could use a prepare for a segue function to pass the text of the table view cell to the next view controller. You do this by creating a variable in the other view controller (the one that you are going to pass data to) and later accessing it from the other view controller and changing its value.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "reportBug" {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! WebViewController
            destinationViewController.reason = "reportBug"

        }
        else if segue.identifier == "provideFeedback" {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! WebViewController
            destinationViewController.reason = "provideFeedback"
        }
    }
```

Here is more about passing data between viewcontrollers : [Passing data between View Controllers in Swift (From TableView to DetailViewController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643752/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift-from-tableview-to-detailviewcont/33645068#33645068)

Hope this helps

---

EDIT:
Here is the struct I am using :

```
struct homeworkTableViewCellData {
    let homeworkName : String!
    let className : String!
    let dateName : String!
    let colorImage : UIImage!
    let homeworkIdentifier : String!
}
```

I have initialized my homeworkArray with this struct. When I am calling a value from the cell, I am picking one from in the struct.

To set the table view with a struct is more organized. This is a good video that teaches you how to set it up (if you are want to do that) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAWO9rldyUE&list=LL--UalPCi7F16WzDFhMEg7w&index=20&t=921s

Comment: Rosalie I have a quick question, are you available?

Comment: I am available now

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I don't have the most experience with Swift and cannot seem to get your code to work. Please take a look at the update I posted

Comment: I believe what the issue is right now is that myCell is the whole Cell right? What I am grabbing in my code (homeworkIdentifier) is one of the values in the struct of the cell. Are you using a struct?

Comment: Yes myCell is the whole cell. How can I create a struct to identify the text in the cell?

Comment: You could check the video in the updated answer. Then, you could grab that value using the struct and save it in a variable. You would pass the value of the variable to the next view controller using the prepare for segue method :) Also, this Stack Overflow post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182847/how-to-detect-tableview-cell-touched-or-clicked-in-swift.

Comment: Ok, I managed to turn the text from each row into a printable string value, using a slightly different method (take a look at my update)..can the value of "titleStr" be passed to the next viewController the same way?

Comment: When printing "titleStr" it prints the correct text value from whichever cell is selected

Comment: Yes then you can go ahead and pass that titleStr to another variable made in your other class using the prepare for segue method